# Student not giving mid-project report and not coming to defense

Tags: ethics, research-undergraduate

Context:

I am a researcher in a Western European university. 
As part of a masters courses in my uni, students have a rather long project to do (each student has its own project). This project is divided in two parts: an analysis part (short, they need to understand their project and state how they want to achieve it) and an experimentation part (the main part of the project, they need to achieve as much as they can). Each part is evaluated with a report and a small defence.

In this context, I have a student working on a project I submitted. The first part of the project has now ended and I have the following problems:

- the student lied to me on the submission date for the report
- they did not submit anything
- they did not come to their defence

What I did as an advisor:

- during the project: took several hours to explain the project and provided help to prepare the experiments (they are not done right now)
- offered my help for writing the report (asked for the student to send drafts regularly and to ask about anything unclear, never received any draft)
- I was present at the defence to help them if they could not answer questions

What happened then:

- they scored the worst marked for the first part of the project
- I did not received any explanation nor excuses
- I can decide whether I accept that they continue the project or not

So my question is: what do you advise in such context?

Here I listed a few options:

- let them do the rest of the project and help them with the experimentations (note that at this point I do not expect any workable result anymore, but maybe they will work better than on the first part)
- forbid the student to finish the project (it is likely that they won't be able to validate the project anyway due to their mark at the first evaluation, and I will have more time for my research, perhaps doing their project by myself)
- ask the student to submit the report before deciding (we will loose some time on the rest of the project, but it was explicitly asked to submit this report and I could make sure that they understood what they need to do).

Any help / advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the university guideline say? If you decide, then the question is: can they carry out the experiment without evidence that they understand the theoretical part?

Comment: University told me that I was free to choose whatever option

Comment: Also, I can help them by saying "Do X and try Y", as for my side I know what should be done,but I fear that in the end we will both lose our time

Comment: Have you physically sit with and/or spoken with the student in person recently? Is it possible they're currently sitting alone in their house suffering from depression? It's not unheard of for people considering suicide to just stop participating in the world.

Comment: I saw them a few days before the report submission and they told me that everything was fine and that they would send me a draft of their report the same day. Receiving nothing, I decided to ask for the draft again the next day and they just kept saying "I'm gonna give you this at the end of the day"

Now I want to meet them again but I have no response from them. I know that the responsible of the masters degree is looking for them as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Failing a student should always be the last option, but in this case it definitely sounds like a valid option. You should communicate with whoever is responsible for the master's degree or those projects for the details, but in general I would report the grade for the whole project as failed. Continuing will not only be a waste of time and money but depending on the experiments might actually be a danger to the student and others.

If what you say about the students behaviour is true and they deliberately lied to you, it might also be a valid point to not accept the student for any of your future projects (I assume you are not the only one offering them) as you may not be able to grade them impartially after what happened.

On the converse though, whatever you do, be careful in how you do it and how you present it to the student. Right now you know only part of the story. The student might simply be lazy and lying about it, but there might equally be some urgent private or psychological reasons for it. And failing such an important class and possibly their whole degree might be what convinces a clinically depressive student to do something irreversible. It's not your job to deal with this, but if you suspect something, your university might offer some psychological student counseling you could involve as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually it's very hard to make a decision as long as I do not have any face to face discussion with them. But right now, the facts are not on their side

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you expect here, given they have submitted nothing then they will have nothing to experiment on.

So, basically they have failed this assignment and will need to replace it if possible. That will depend on the regulations in force at your institution.

Comment: Actually, as I submitted the project I can just tell them "Do X and try Y"
Also I can not check whether they understand everything or not

Comment: @belitd You state "they did not submit anything", but did not mention that you submitted on their behalf. Should that be taken into consideration as their work?

Comment: My sentence may have been unclear, I just meant that I **submitted the subject**, I didn't do their work, but I certainly know how I would do it. 

And they chose to work on this project based on the 1-page document I wrote stating the main goals and giving some technical hints. I never submitted a report on their behalf and would certainly not do that.